# Convert JSON structure to Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization

I need to convert this -

```
{"Header":{ "Number" : 101, "Total" : 100.00},
"Items" : [
{"Line" : 1, "Description": "Item 1", "Price" : 25.00, "Quantity" : 2},
{"Line" : 2, "Description": "Item 2", "Price" : 50.00, "Quantity" : 1}
]}
```

to this -

```
[
{"HeaderNumber" : 101, "Total" : 100.00, "Line" : 1, "Description": "Item 1", "Price" : 25.00, "Quantity" : 2},
{"HeaderNumber" : 101, "Total" : 100.00, "Line" : 2, "Description": "Item 2", "Price" : 50.00, "Quantity" : 1}
]
enter code here
```

Any high level ideas on how I can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried and in what language  solution would be?

Comment: I want to try this out in C#. I'm not getting a starting point to achieve this. Any first hand ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Create a JSON Model class for that you can use [JSONToCSharp](http://json2csharp.com). Once you get your JSON result store like this

```
JsonModel[] result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel[]>(postResult);
```

It will convert your result into an Array of Model class. Then you can iterate over it using foreach loop.

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
     item.PropertyName;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear initially. Can I achieve this using XML structure?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
public class Header
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public double Total { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public int Line { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }

    public class Source
    {
        public Header Header { get; set; }
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class Target
    {
        public int HeaderNumber { get; set; }
        public double Total { get; set; }
        public int Line { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var src = @"{""Header"":{ ""Number"" : 101, ""Total"" : 100.00},
""Items"" : [
{""Line"" : 1, ""Description"": ""Item 1"", ""Price"" : 25.00, ""Quantity"" : 2},
{""Line"" : 2, ""Description"": ""Item 2"", ""Price"" : 50.00, ""Quantity"" : 1}
]}";

            var srcObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Source>(src);

            var targetObj = srcObj.Items.Select(s => new Target()
            {
                HeaderNumber = srcObj.Header.Number,
                Total = srcObj.Header.Total,
                Description = s.Description,
                Line = s.Line,
                Price = s.Price,
                Quantity = s.Quantity
            });
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(targetObj));
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear initially. Can I achieve this using XML structure?